# Build Failed due to missing JavaScript engine

Tags: java, xml, javafx, build, javascript-engine

I'm just starting with JavaFX, and I encountered 2 Build errors when I hit RUN on my project. I'm using Netbeans 21 and JDK 21. After I run my project, I click Run File on the Main file, and it displays this error:

[image: Build failure]

```
Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself.
GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option.

BUILD FAILED
...\jfx-impl.xml:1251: The following error occurred while executing this line:
...\jfx-impl.xml:1259: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
```

I've been looking for information to solve it, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Documentation on [getting started with JavaFX is at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).